# scala: type equality of two variables

Tags: scala, reflection, types, equality

I have two `Map[String, T]`s, where `T` is an instance of subtype of `Fruit`.  I need to construct new Map from two Maps, where the key is the common key names from the two maps, and the value is the `Seq[Fruit]` iff the values from the two maps shares the same type.

```
class Fruit

case class Apple() extends Fruit
case class Banana(num: Int) extends Fruit
case class Orange() extends Fruit
```

For example, if I have following two maps:

```
val map1 = Map("first" -> Apple(),
               "second" -> Banana(3),
               "third" -> Orange())

val map2 = Map("first" -> Orange(),
               "second" -> Banana(4),
               "third" -> Orange())
```

I need the result map, `map3` which has following members:

```
generateMap(map1: Map[String, Fruit], map2: Map[String, Fruit]): Map[String, Seq[Fruit]]

=> results a map look like

    Map("second" -> Seq(Banana(3), Banana(4)),
        "third"  -> Seq(Orange(), Orange())
```

I'm not sure how to write a function, `generateMap`.  Could anyone help me to implement that? (using Scala 2.11.x)

Note that the class definitions (Fruits and others) are fixed, so I cannot modify them.

Answer (score 1):

```
scala> val r: Map[String, Seq[Fruit]] = (map1.toList ++ map2.toList).
   groupBy(x => x._1).
   mapValues(lst => lst.map(x => x._2)).
   .filter { 
     case (key, lst) => lst.forall(x =>
             x.getClass == lst.head.getClass)
   }

r: Map[String, Seq[Fruit]] = Map(third -> List(Orange(), Orange()), 
    second -> List(Banana(3), Banana(4)))
```

Comment: thanks, but the result is different from what I expected.  Because the map1("first") has the different type from map2("first"), the generated output should not have "first".

Answer (score 0):

```css
val m3 = (map1.toSeq ++ map2.toSeq). // Combine the maps
   groupBy (x=>x._1). //Group by the original keys
   map{case (k,lst)=> (k, lst.map(x=> x._2))}. //Strip the keys from the grouped sequences
   filter{case (_, lst) => lst.forall(i => lst.head.getClass == i.getClass)}. //Filter out hetergeneous seqs
    toMap // Make a map
```

Answer (score 0):

Without forall:

```
(map1.toList ++ map2.toList).groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2))
  .filter(_._2.map(_.getClass).toSet.tail.isEmpty)

Map(third -> List(Orange(), Orange()), second -> List(Banana(3), Banana(4)))
```

This version requires a little more (but still linear inside `filter`) CPU and memory than version with `forall`, so you should use it only for small collections.